# Perl printf line breaks

Tags: perl

Looking to add a line break after every 16 bytes of the 100 bytes printed from j. All 100 bytes are currently printed on one line at the moment.

Any assistance would be great full, thanks.

```
for ($j = 6; $j < 106; $j++)
        {
            printf("%02X ", hex(@bytes[$j]));
        }
        printf("\t");
```

Thanks all. I approached it another way. In the end the visual aspect was not a concern as I ended up printing to file anyway. This data then gets pasted in a hex editor so formatting was a forethought rather than a need be. The below is now outputting all the data I was looking for in the end rather than a predetermined length.

```
for ($j = 6; $j < @bytes; $j = $j + 1)      
        {
            printf outfile ("%02X ", hex(@bytes[$j]));
        }
        printf("\n");
```

Comment: [`pack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) ?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I appreciate it.

Think I'm trying to achieve something that will not work this way. Have just found that some lines that are processed may have 10 bytes where others may have 200 bytes. When using a loop it means I end up with 00  at the end to fill the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`splice()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice) to grab 16 elements at a time from your array.

I've also switched to using [`say()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say), [`join()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join), [`map()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) and [`sprintf()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @bytes = map { int(rand(255)) } 0..200;

# As splice is destructive, take a copy of the array.
# Also, let's remove those first six elements and any
# after index 106.

my @data = @bytes[6 .. 105];

while (my @row = splice @data, 0, 16) {
  say join ' ', map { sprintf '%02X', $_ } @row;
}
```

**Update:** A few more Perl tips for you.

- Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your Perl programs. And fix the problems they will show you.
- `@bytes[$j]` is better written as `$bytes[$j]` (as it's a single value). That's one of the things `use warnings` will tell you about.
- `for ($j = 6; $j < 106; $j++)` is probably better written as `for my $j (6 .. 105)`. Less chance of "off-by-one" errors.
- Actually, as you're just using `$j` to get the element from the array, you probably want to just iterate across the elements of the array directly - `for my $elem (@bytes[6 .. 105])` (and then using `$elem` in place of `$bytes[$j]`).

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize some `$counter` and print `\n` once `$counter % 16` equal `0`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @bytes = map { int(rand(255)) } 0..200;
my $counter = 1;

for ( @bytes[6..106] ) {
    printf "%02X ", $_;
    print "\n" unless $counter++ % 16;
}

print "\n";
```

Output sample

```
C9 CA E7 66 13 F5 56 BE 08 68 E4 22 93 77 E0 14
08 4F F3 AD CC F4 66 DE 6C BB 1B E6 CE F3 13 DD
AE 6A CD 9B 5E 98 1F D4 2E C5 80 4B 3E 8E BC BF
5B 27 F9 0D 97 AB 26 C0 11 2D 1D 95 CE 26 3C D8
3C D8 A4 06 0A 48 0D 45 53 28 7E 5D D2 AD 90 5C
03 32 95 48 F6 DB 20 90 A7 62 41 3D D7 AB 7C 3B
CF 3D 0D C2 DA
```

Note: index from 6 to 106 gives 101 element

Comment: Since the original used a c-style `for` with a `<` instead of `<=`, it was only running from 6 to 105.

Answer (score 1):

Short and fast:

```perl
sub hex_dump {
   my $i = 0;
   my $d = uc unpack 'H*', pack 'C*', @_;
   $d =~ s{ ..\K(?!\z) }{ ++$i % 16 ? " " : "\n" }xseg;
   return "$d\n";
}

print hex_dump(@bytes[6..105]);
```

---

There's also the very clean `splice` loop approach.

```perl
sub hex_dump {
   my $d = '';
   $d .= join(" ", map sprintf("%02X", $_), splice(@_, 0, 16)) . "\n" while @_;
   return $d;
}

print hex_dump(@bytes[6..105]);
```

Because this approach produces a line at a time, it's great for recreating the traditional hex dump format (with offset and printable characters shown).

```
$ hexdump -C a.pl
00000000  75 73 65 20 73 74 72 69  63 74 3b 0a 75 73 65 20  |use strict;.use |
00000010  77 61 72 6e 69 6e 67 73  3b 0a 0a 73 75 62 20 68  |warnings;..sub h|
00000020  65 78 5f 64 75 6d 70 20  7b 0a 20 20 20 6d 79 20  |ex_dump {.   my |
...
000000a0  74 65 73 20 3d 20 30 2e  2e 32 35 35 3b 0a 0a 70  |tes = 0..255;..p|
000000b0  72 69 6e 74 20 68 65 78  5f 64 75 6d 70 28 40 62  |rint hex_dump(@b|
000000c0  79 74 65 73 5b 36 2e 2e  31 30 35 5d 29 3b 0a     |ytes[6..105]);.|
000000cf
```

---

You could also use a for loop. You would iterate over the indexes, and print either a space or a line feed depending on the index of the byte you're printing.

```perl
sub hex_dump {
   my $d = '';
   for my $i (0..$#_) {
      $d .= sprintf("%02X%s", $_[$i], $i == $#_ || $i % 16 == 15 ? "\n" : " ");
   }

   return $d;
}

print hex_dump(@bytes[6..105]);
```